# `mode()` always seems to return 'n'

Tags: vimscript

So I do a visual selection and hit a `vnoremap` which calls a function and executes `mode()`, but everything it ever does it output `n`, indicating I'm in normal mode, even though that is certainly not true.

```
vnoremap <silent> qb :<c-u>call <sid>func()<cr>

function! func()
  echo mode()
endfunction
```

Comment: [Why would you expect](http://darkpan.com/files/vim.svg) to execute an `omap`-ing from visual mode? You should be executing an `xmap` (preferably) or `vmap` form visual mode.

Comment: Actually it is a `vmap` (and an `omap`)

Comment: If you are executing a `vmap`/`xmap` then you know the mode is visual mode already. It is a common vim script idiom to pass some argument to a function call to let the function know it came from visual mode (You can see an example `:h g@`). If you really need the mode from the mapping then you need to convert your mapping to a map expression (See `:h :map-<expr>`).

Comment: `mode()` is more or less usefull for statusline functions, else you usually won't see other modes than normal or ex-mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `visual mode`, press `:`, then press enter or escape.  The selection is gone and you're in `normal mode`.  This is what's happening with your maps and why `mode()` returns `n`.

To deal with this, you need tell your function that it *should be* in visual mode.  You already know that it will be since you're using `vmap`.

```
vnoremap <silent> qb :<c-u>call <sid>func(1)<cr>

function! func(visual)
  if a:visual
    normal! gv
  endif
  echo mode()
endfunction
```

`echo mode()` will then give you the correct mode.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has left Visual mode by the time `Func` is called.
The following will get `mode()` to echo`'V'`:

```
function! Func()
    normal! V
    echoerr mode()
endfunction

call Func()
```